# Nestjs unit test adding second service module manual mock did not work

Tags: mocking, nestjs, ts-jest

I use Nest developing an app backend, when I write unit test, I found if I just add one service module manual mock, mocking works fine. But if I add manual mock for 2nd service module, the test went wrong with error "... is not a function" which works perfectly fine when there is just one service module mocking. The test framework is Jest, does anyone know why this happening?

Following is one example, in reader controller unit test, original just use readerService manual mock in **mocks** folder, all test case passed. Then I need add a tokenService dependency, so I add tokenService manual mock also in **mocks** folder, then all the test cases (which all passed previously) did not pass because of "this.readerService.*** is not a function", looks like adding 2nd manual mock caused 1st manual mock failed somewhere. Following is part of unit test code:

```
import { ReaderController } from './reader.controller';
import { ReaderService } from './reader.service';
import { TokenService } from './token.service';

jest.mock('./reader.service').mock('./token.service');

describe('ReaderController', () => {
  let readerController: ReaderController;
  let readerService: ReaderService;
  let tokenService: TokenService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      controllers: [ReaderController],
      providers: [ReaderService, TokenService],
    }).compile();

    readerController = module.get<ReaderController>(ReaderController);
    readerService = module.get<ReaderService>(ReaderService);
    tokenService = module.get<TokenService>(TokenService);
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

describe('getProfile', () => {
    describe('when getProfile is called', () => {
      let reader: Reader;

      beforeEach(async () => {
        reader = await readerController.getProfile(readerStub()._id);
      });

      test('then it should call readerService', () => {
        expect(readerService.getProfile).toHaveBeenCalledWith(readerStub()._id);
      });

      test('then it should return a reader object', () => {
        expect(reader).toEqual(readerStub());
      });
    });
  });
```

Following is manual mock of ReaderService:

```
export const ReaderService = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  register: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(readerStub()),
  findOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(readerStub()),
  getProfile: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(readerStub()),
  updateProfile: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(readerStub()._id),
  changePwd: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(readerStub().username),
  login: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(accessTokenStub()),
  tokenRefresh: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(accessTokenStub()),
  logout: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(readerStub()._id),
  addFavourBook: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(2),
  getFavourBookList: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(readerStub().favouriteBook),
  delFavourBook: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(2),
  getReadBooks: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([bookStub()]),
  getReadHistory: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(readerStub().readHistory),
});
```

Following is manual mock of TokenService:

```
export const TokenService = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  createToken: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(tokenStub()),
  verifyToken: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true),
  delToken: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(tokenStub().readerName),
  resetPwd: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(tokenStub().readerName),
  verifyEmail: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(tokenStub().readerName),
});
```

All these mock files located in **mocks** which under folder of test file, all these setting follows Jest document. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I just found work around, use one major service with manual mocking, then directly add mock definitions of 2nd service in the test, just before the test function (1st describe). Then in test module definition define mock for 2nd service (1st service just use original name in provides), then both mocks will work properly. I think maybe Nest  has some limitation about using 2 service mocks manually in **mocks** fold.